# Connect Spring to RDS DB

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

I am desperately trying to connect my java webapp to my RDS PostgreSQL Database.
Using localhost config it's no problem. Changing the application.properties file to the remote DB makes Spring throw the following error when running the app:

```
2016-11-02 11:21:05.852 ERROR 60478 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "DB" does not exist
```

My application.properties file looks as follows:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://ec2instance:portnumber/DB
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

I connect to the instance the following way:

```
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver"); 
    String url = "jdbc:postgresql://instanceNAme.instance.amazonaws.com:5432/DB";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("user", " ");
    props.setProperty("password", " ");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

Any clues as to how I can fix this? I'm pretty unexperienced in using spring, so any advice would be well appreciated!

Comment: What's unclear about "*FATAL: database "DB" **does not exist***"? You need to supply a database name that exists on your Postgres server

Comment: the databse DOES exist - and the name is correct. The issue seems to be coming from "Unable to create initial connections of pool.".

Comment: I am telling you it is there. The issue has to be spring related. I can connect per ssh without any issue, as well as pgadmin, and the aws eclipse plugin.